# How Do I Play a Watson Text-to-Speech Response through my Speakers?

Tags: node.js, text-to-speech, watson

I am trying to add Text-to-Speech to a ChatBot on a web browser using NodeJS, where I want to show the text and to play the speetch when I get a response.

I have searched and found the following example that creates a WAV file, wich works good.

```
// Pipe the synthesized text to a file
text_to_speech.synthesize(params).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.wav'));
```

Instead of creating a file, how can I just play the response directly on my laptop speakers?

Comment: It's too broad for one question IMHO. You need a client-side audio player for an audio record you are creating server-side. First you want to deliver the audio to your clients somehow (google "node js audio streaming server"). Then you need a client-side audio player.

Comment: You could use the Speaker Library and pipe your stream to it instead of saving it as a file.

Comment: Hi, @Alaska, I tried with the speaker library but for some reason it always plays the same text, and I have verified that the input text to watson TTS is diferent. Exemple of my code: var Speaker = require('speaker');var speaker = new Speaker();watson_text_to_speech.synthesize(params).pipe(speaker);

Comment: Hi @enkryptor, I have seen this as you said, and i would like to share my solution (still needs work though). I now save my wav file on the server side and on the client side i have an audio tag. But here now i have two other issues. One is that the file is always named output.wav, the browers caches the audio and doesn't reload on chrome, only works on firefox. The other is that i have a Timeout on the client side to wait until the file is updated by the server.

Answer (score 0):

I battled with this for a while now. I was running in on my raspberry pi and was running into problems with the speaker solution.

The below worked for me.

```
var Sound = require('node-aplay');


var f =text_to_speech.synthesize(params).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.wav'));

f.on('finish', function () {

  new Sound('output.wav').play();

  console.log("Done");
});
```